# Binding the source to an iframe with Vue JS shows up empty iframe?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently, I have an Vue JS app which I need to bind the iframe source to the iframe. I have used the suggested method of v-bind:src="" but using Inspect Element I can see that the body tag of the iframe is empty. Can this be done or am I better giving up my treasure hunt?

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    <div class="responsive-iframe">
      <iframe v-bind:src="maps.treasureMapFrame"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then my JS is as below;

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            message: "Find Treasure",
            maps: [
                {
                  treasureMapFrame:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1230838.6815658903!2d-3.2675559393922833!3d52.948750511868894!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4870be1abfbc770f%3A0x474d30c2c81f0893!2sTreasure%20Island%20Play%20Ltd!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sfr!4v1571778541141!5m2!1sen!2sfr"
                }   
            ]
        };
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to select the first item in your array:

```
<iframe v-bind:src="maps[0].treasureMapFrame"></iframe>
```